# One kernel thread can monopolize core?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

Although grabbing one processor core by a specific thread is not a good thing, I would like to make one kernel thread runs on a particular core without preemption and interrupts to get performance benefit for a while (same as we pin user process to one core)

After my kernel driver is loaded and when the kernel function is invoked through IOCTL, it disables local interrupts using local_irq_disable() function. What I expected was because interrupt for that specific core has been disabled, kernel thread should not be scheduled out from that core and it should run until local_irq_enble() function is invoked.

However, after a few seconds, kernel watchdog is invoked and machine is rebooted automatically with some watchdog messages. Although I pinned my thread to logical processor 3, watch dog prints that kernel cannot be rebooted because of another logical core is stuck, for example 4 not 3.

How the kernel thread can be scheduled out even though the local interrupt for that processor has been disabled? Is there any method to disable interrupts and preemption for that specific core for a while? And if the watchdog is problem which watchdog has to be turned off? watchdog? nmi-watchdog?

```c
static long unlocked_ioctl(struct file *filp, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long argp)
{
        int cpuNum = 0;
        switch (cmd) {
                case MON:
                        printk("Monitoring starts\n");
                        cpuNum = smp_processor_id();
                        printk("Monitor starts to run at core %d\n", cpuNum);
                        local_irq_disable();
                        while(1);
                        break;
                default:
                        return -EINVAL;
                break;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Instead of putting some logic in the while loop, I intentionally make it run inside an infinite loop. Let's assume that the current core running this ioctl function in my driver runs at 4 at the beginning, but after few seconds, kernel starts to rebooted automatically with watchdog's message such as processor 5 not 4 doesn't responds.

Comment: Drivers are not pinned to a core, processes are.  Interrupts are not processes, so use a different mechanism.  No one can help you if you don't show any code, any commands that you ran, or any results or error messages.

Comment: @stark Sorry I will upload the code soon. BTW, after one thread starts to run, if irq is disabled for that core with local_irq_disable(), it should not be switched to the other cores right? Because no one can interrupt that kernel thread until it gives up by itself.

Comment: I think your issue is that the kernel has decided your lockedout core has gone crazy and attempts to rectify the situation.  You need to inform the kernel that your core is no longer available for scheduling.  You could try cpu_offline as a hack, but the correct solution is to set yourself to the highest possible priority in the highest scheduling group.  You will still lose a few clocks to the odd maintenance interrupt, but it will work.